# Eclipse IDE not starting on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, java, eclipse

I've tried to install eclipse with the official installer from the website first, hit an error when starting the IDE after the installation and then thought, screw them, I'll use the version from the repositories, that should work better. But, to my unpleasant surprise, it does not work either!

That version too give me trouble even starting the IDE:

[image]

Usually when I install something from the repos, I expect it to run out of the box and I don't have a clue what the error message is trying or not trying to tell me.

Infos:

- Xubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- eclipse version: unknown, because of the following error when trying to `eclipse --version`:

  ```
  Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m'
  Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
  Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
  ```
- java version `java -version`:

  ```
  openjdk version "9-internal"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
  ```

  I installed java with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk openjdk-9-demo openjdk-9-doc openjdk-9-jre-headless openjdk-9-source
  ```

  `which java`:

  ```
  /usr/bin/java
  ```

What's up with eclipse and how can I fix these issues?

Comment: Are you using the package openjdk-9-jdk or are you using openjdk-9-jre?

Comment: @Booming I am not sure what it is using, but I added the installation command for java, which I used to my question text.

Comment: did you have an error message while installing openjdk-9-jre? Cause this keeps happening on my virtualbox and it also happended on my machine. So I think it is using the jre.  This would explain the errors.

Comment: You might want to try it with java 8, looks like 9 is a beta version. I use Eclipse on this version too, tried to install java 9 but it did not work.

Comment: @Booming Now I am experiencing problems properly cleaning openjdk 9 out of my system and making it use openjdk 8. For example `sudo update-alternatives --config java` results in: `update-alternatives: warning: /etc/alternatives/java is dangling; it will be updated with best choice There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
Nothing to configure.`
Although I `apt-get remove` all the packages I `apt-get install`ed with the line I posted in my question text. This is tedious : (

Comment: @Booming Your information solved the issue. After purging everything that has `java` in its name and then running the install openjdk stuff line with `9` replaced by `8`, I was finally able to use eclipse (both, repo version and downloaded installer version from their website) without issues so far. Could you make this an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Booming mentioned in a comment, that OpenJDK9 is beta still and indeed uninstalling OpenJDK9 and installing OpenJDK8 fixed all problems.

I had to `apt-get purge` all things Java and then reinstall OpenJDK8 to make it work:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge java
$ sudo apt-get purge openjdk
```

Then to check if it is really gone:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And installing again:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-demo openjdk-8-doc openjdk-8-jre-headless openjdk-8-source
```